# Vue - access data in component outside of Vue - Single file component

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, laravel-mix

How to access and change data of compontent out side the component and Vue instance but inside single-file-component?

Component in sigle file like:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                lock: true,
                connection: '',
                login: true,
                message: {
                    time: '',
                    nick: '',
.......................
```

The file is chat.vue

Main Vue app:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '.app',

    components: {
        Chat
    }

});
```

And I need to access and example data from something like

```
Socket.onopen = function(e)
    {
        Chat.connection = 'Zostałeś połączony pomyślnie!';
        Chat.lock = false;
    };
```

Outside of component but in this component file

tried something like

`Chat.message.nick = 'xxxx';` but doesn't work

`this.message.nick = 'xxx';` doesn't work too + I got error: `named exports are not supported in *.vue files.`

`var chat = export default....` doesn't work too, blowup

And many things... I don't know...

the only thing I worked out is to use `ref="Chat"` on component in HTML. But it is not what I want, it allows me to reference my component's data but in not in this component vue single file but in my main js file

I need to reference data and change it in this compontent vue single file

Comment: Will there only ever be *one* of that component in the Vue?

Comment: @Bert yes :). only one